# How to check if 2 variables in a class is equal?

Tags: c#, class, list

I've tried to check if 2 variables in a class, or if 2 classes are equal, but my messagebox still doesn't show.

Maptiles : this is a list, with classes, and each class has variables: ID, X and Y

Mapindex : this is the variable to loop through all classes in maptiles list.

Mapnumber: this variable starts on 1, I use it to check on all classes

Here's code:

```
            for (int mapIndex = 0; mapIndex < MapTiles.Count; mapIndex++)
            {
                if (mapIndex + mapNumber >= MapTiles.Count)
                {
                    break;
                }
                if(MapTiles[mapIndex].Equals(MapTiles[mapIndex+mapNumber])) 
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("REMOVE");
                }
                mapNumber++;
            }
```

So question is, how to make it show, or how to check if 2 classes are the same??
Thanx.

Comment: do you want to find if they are really Equal (the same object in two places in the array), or if they are equivalent (different objects having the same ID, X, and Y values)?

Comment: i need to check if maptiles[0].X maptiles[0].Y maptiles[0].ID is maptiles[1].X maptiles[1].Y maptiles[1].ID

Comment: then I would go with implementing your own Equal method on the class as suggested below

Comment: @Marcus - Why don't you simply compare those specfic properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class needs to override Object.Equals() at least for that comparison to work out. Also implementing IEquatable is a good idea.

More information: [Guidelines for Overloading Equals() and Operator == (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to override the equals operator.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think is more natural way in .NET is override Equals() and just compare objects inside that method.

You can implement whatever comparison complexity you want, it's important to structure in ".NET expected way", so someone after 2 years will able understan at least a logic of a stuff.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can as others have said can override Equals (and also GetHashCode).

However if you don't want to do this or can't do that you can write a class that implements [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx).

Although implementing IEqualityComparer is not required (you could just write a method that did the comparision) it would prove useful if you decided to go use a Linq expression like [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) on a collection

For example

```
class YourImplementedComparer: IEqualityComparer<Item> {

    public bool Equals(Item x, Item y) {
        return x.X== y.X &&
            x.Y == y.Y &&
            x.Y == y.Y
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Item obj) {
        return obj.X.GetHashCode() ^
            obj.Y.GetHashCode() ^
            obj.ID.GetHashCode() ;
    }
}
```

then using it with distinct

```
MapTiles  =  MapTiles.Distinct(new YourImplementedComparer)
```